# Building Chromium on Mac

Tags: macos, fetch, chromium, gn

I have been trying to build Chromium on mac. I have been following the doc [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/mac_build_instructions.md#System-requirements)

**Fetch will not end properly and will exit with the following stack trace:**

```
Error: Command 'vpython src/build/landmines.py' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/chromium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 301, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 296, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 290, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 133, in init
    self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 78, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 68, in run
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'sync', '--no-history')' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I have .glient in directory but no .gclient_entries.

**And when I run gclient sync : projects are synced but it exits with stacktrace:**

```
________ running 'vpython src/build/landmines.py' in '/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/chromium'
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540361-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] goroutine 1:
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540400-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #0 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/python/find.go:88 - python.Find()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540414-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]   annotation #0:
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540423-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]     reason: no Python found
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540470-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]   annotation #1:
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540490-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]     reason: failed to get version for: "/Users/admin/anaconda/bin/python2.7"
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540506-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]   annotation #2:
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540517-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]     reason: failed to parse version from: "2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)"
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540528-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]   annotation #3:
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540542-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]     reason: non-canonical Python version string: "2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)"
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540557-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] 
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540567-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #1 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/config.go:253 - venv.(*Config).resolvePythonInterpreter()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540575-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]   reason: could not find Python for: 2.7.0
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540586-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] 
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540594-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #2 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/config.go:175 - venv.(*Config).makeEnv()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540601-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]   reason: failed to resolve system Python interpreter
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540611-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] 
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540619-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #3 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:122 - venv.With()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540629-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238]   reason: failed to initialize empty probe environment
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540637-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] 
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540644-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #4 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/run.go:72 - vpython.Run()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540652-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #5 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:261 - application.(*application).mainImpl()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540666-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #6 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:349 - application.(*Config).Main.func1()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540674-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #7 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/support.go:45 - application.run()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540685-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #8 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:348 - application.(*Config).Main()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540692-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #9 vpython/main.go:92 - main.mainImpl()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540700-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #10 vpython/main.go:98 - main.main()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540711-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #11 runtime/proc.go:185 - runtime.main()
[E2017-12-11T14:20:13.540718-05:00 36600 0 annotate.go:238] #12 runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337 - runtime.goexit()
Error: Command 'vpython src/build/landmines.py' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriversource/chromium
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 3):

Was on IRC Chromium:

Found out that "Anaconda" build for python was not recognized by gclicent. Once I removed this from $PATH, all worked perfectly.

Rock n roll.